# Что означает единственный знак ; в строке?

Tags: c++

Что означает строка в `main`? Для чего такая конструкция нужна?

```
int main() {
  ;
}
```

Comment: ничего, просто пустое тело функции

Comment: @VTT пустое - это int main() { }

Comment: `int main() { ; } ` точно такое же пустое, ровно как и `int main() { ;; } ` или `int main() { ;;; } `

Comment: Не круто :) Где-то тут пробегало `int main() {[](){}();}` :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пустой statement присутствует в языках С и С++ со времен динозавров. Например

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i);
```

В данном случае последняя `;` - это самостоятельный пустой statement, представляющий тело цикла. Или

```
switch (i)
{
  case 0:
  case 1:
    printf("Hello\n"); 
    break;
  default:
    printf("Hello World\n"); 
    break;
  case 2:;
}
```

В дaнном случае метка `case 2:` помечает пустой statement.

Однако в современном С++ вопрос имеет интересный подтекст: что это - пустой statement или пустое объявление? В списке дефектов болтается [дефект 2188](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2188), который, возможно, посвящен именно этому вопросу, но его описание, что характерно, пусто :)

Comment: Почему он присутствует?

Comment: "Я понимаю, что они не пересекаются. Но *ПОЧЕМУ* они не пересекаются?" Ералаш

Comment: @user318688: Почему бы и нет? Пустой statement может использоваться для циклов с пустым телом, для постановки меток и т.п.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за пример

Comment: Насчёт объявления... Ведь любое объявление есть statement, значит это И пустой statement И пустое объявление

Comment: @user318688: В С++ объявление есть statement, но грамматически это разные типы statement: один вариант разбора `declaration -> empty-declaration`, другой `statement -> expression->statement -> expression;` с пустым `expression`. Как должна вести себя грамматика? Разницы в итоге, наверное, никакой, но тем не менее.

Comment: @AnT понял, о чём вы. О том, как идёт разбор. Возможно, это есть в разделе про трансляцию